# Is it possible to predefine 'msg.value' when calling a function in an external contract?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, ether, transfer

I am new to developing smart contracts and have had some trouble trying to troubleshoot a solution to this problem.

I have two smart contracts...

**Contract X: (The bank - Balance 100 ETH)**

```
contract X {
   function transfer(address dest){
     dest.send(msg.value);
   }
}
```

and...

**Contract Y: (The Forwarder - Balance ZERO ETH)**

```
contract Y {
  function < somehow call x.transfer >
  <set x.msg.value to some number ignoring the actual msg.value of the call>
}
```

Contract X will store some funds and contract Y will be used to call the 'transfer' function of contract X and provide a destination address to transfer funds to. The problem I am having is that I don't know how (or if it is possible) to set the value of 'msg.value' in contract X from the function call in contract Y.

Currently 'msg.value' in contract X is only ever zero since contract Y will not be used to store any funds (besides small amounts of wei for gas).

Does anybody know of a way to parse a specified 'msg.value' over a function call?

Side note: There are more to these contracts although it's not necessary to include them here.

**Any help is greatly appreciated!**

**EDIT:**

The desired result would look something like this:

**contract Y > contract X:**

- `msg.value` for this transaction will be **zero** (no funds sent from Y to X)
- Y will supply `dest` address for contract X's `transfer` function
- Y will supply `msg.value` for contract X's `transfer` function (**This is my main isssue**)

**contract X > Destionation (dest) address:**

- `transfer` function will use the `msg.value` and `dest` values provided by contract Y above
- `msg.value` will never be zero

I guess the question is really if it is possible to parse a `msg.value` to the external contract (contract X) to use as the `msg.value` for X's `transfer` - that is not the zero `msg.value` from the the Y to X?

Answer (score 2):

To send funds in a function call to another contract you can use something like this:

```
contract X {
  function transfer(address dest, uint amount) public { ... }
}
contract Y {
  function take() public payable {
    // Reference an existing contract at an address
    X ref = X(addressOfX);
    // or if creating a new instance at a new address: X ref = new X();
    ref.transfer(destAddress, msg.value);
}
```

That example is missing stuff, but it contains the essentials.

Comment: Thanks Lauri, although in this case contract Y won't be holding any funds. So it won't be sending any ether to contract X. I have edited the question above to make the desired result more clear.

Comment: edited answer now